# HLS: What is the meaning of a stream without URI?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

While trying to implement closed captions support into an iOS video player, I encountered a sample stream of Apple for which I need some explanation please:

The stream is https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8

When downloading the main manifest, I see these two lines:

> **#EXT-X-MEDIA:** TYPE=**AUDIO**,GROUP-ID="bipbop_audio",LANGUAGE="eng",
>       NAME="BipBop Audio 1",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
>
> **#EXT-X-MEDIA:** TYPE=**AUDIO**,GROUP-ID="bipbop_audio",LANGUAGE="eng",
>   NAME="BipBop Audio 2",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,
>   **URI="alternate_audio_aac_sinewave/prog_index.m3u8"**

Can anybody please explain why the first audio entry does not include a URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it means the audio is part of the video - a separate audio track.

From [section 4.3.4.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#section-4.3.4.2.1) of the HLS specification:

> If the media type is VIDEO or AUDIO, a missing URI attribute
> indicates that the media data for this Rendition is included in the
> Media Playlist of any EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag referencing this
> EXT-X-MEDIA tag.  If the media TYPE is AUDIO and the URI attribute is
> missing, clients MUST assume that the audio data for this Rendition
> is present in every video Rendition specified by the EXT-X-STREAM-INF
> tag.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the codecs  `CODECS=mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d400d`, the first codec in all the renditions is the audio, mp4a.40.2.